# GridBagLayout doesn't accept my rowspan command(gridtheight)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm about to learn Java. And I'm trying to write a GUI for a simple calculator with a GridBagLayout.

The problem is that my "+" Button isn't over 2 rows hight. I don't know why? I tried to do it once in the last row with:

> ```
>     c.gridwidth = 1;
>     c.gridy = 4;
>     c.gridx = 3;
>     c.gridheight = 2;
>     c.ipady = 26;
>     subpanel.add(bplus, c);
> ```

and once in the 2. last row.

> ```
>     c.gridwidth = 1;
>     c.gridy = 3;
>     c.gridx = 3;
>     c.gridheight = 2;
>     c.ipady = 26;
>     subpanel.add(bplus, c);
> ```

Here is the hole code of the gui, if you want to test it, maybe you have to adjust the main.

```
package gui;

import classes.Rechner;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

/**
 * Created by tq67 on 17.07.2014.
 */
public class CalculatorGUI extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CalculatorGUI gui = new CalculatorGUI();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);


}

    public CalculatorGUI() {
        setTitle("Calculator");
        setBounds(300, 300, 220, 225);

        JPanel subpanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel headpanel = new JPanel();
        final JTextField input = new JTextField();

        input.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (10 == e.getKeyCode()) {
                    Rechner rechner = new Rechner(input.getText());
                    input.setText(rechner.rechnen().toPlainString());
                }
                if (27 == e.getKeyCode()) {
                    input.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
        ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                input.setText(input.getText() + e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };
        ActionListener resultListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("=")) {
                    Rechner rechner = new Rechner(input.getText());
                    input.setText(rechner.rechnen().toPlainString());
                } else {
                    input.setText("");
                }

            }

            private void calc() {
                Rechner rechner = new Rechner(input.getText());
                input.setText(rechner.rechnen().toPlainString());
            }
        };

        JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
        JButton b0 = new JButton("0");

        JButton bdot = new JButton(".");
        JButton bplus = new JButton("+");
        JButton bminus = new JButton("-");
        JButton bdiv = new JButton("/");
        JButton bmult = new JButton("*");
        JButton bresult = new JButton("=");

        JButton bcancel = new JButton("C");
        b1.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        b2.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        b3.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        b4.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        b5.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        b6.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        b7.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        b8.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        b9.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        b0.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        bdot.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        bplus.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        bminus.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        bdiv.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        bmult.addActionListener(buttonListener);

        bresult.addActionListener(resultListener);
        bcancel.addActionListener(resultListener);

        headpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        subpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();




        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 3;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.ipady = 10;
        headpanel.add(input, c);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(headpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(subpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        subpanel.add(b7, c);
        c.gridx++;
        subpanel.add(b8, c);
        c.gridx++;
        subpanel.add(b9, c);
        c.gridx++;
        subpanel.add(bmult, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        subpanel.add(b4, c);
        c.gridx++;
        subpanel.add(b5, c);
        c.gridx++;
        subpanel.add(b6, c);
        c.gridx++;
        subpanel.add(bdiv, c);


        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        subpanel.add(b1, c);
        c.gridx++;
        subpanel.add(b2, c);
        c.gridx++;
        subpanel.add(b3, c);
        c.gridx++;
        subpanel.add(bminus, c);


        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        subpanel.add(bdot, c);
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx++;
        subpanel.add(b0, c);
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        c.ipady = 26;
        subpanel.add(bplus, c);


        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        subpanel.add(bcancel, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        subpanel.add(bresult, c);

    }
}
```

I read about a bug here in Stackoverflow that when you ouse gridx is bigger then 0 you will have a problem with gridheight...

At the Moment the GUI looks like that:

[image: calc.png]

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things, first, reset the `gridheight` after you've used it

```
c.gridwidth = 1;
c.gridx = 3;
c.gridheight = 2;
c.ipady = 26;
subpanel.add(bplus, c);

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridwidth = 1;
c.ipady = 0;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 4;
// Still using the gridheight of 2...
subpanel.add(bcancel, c);
```

Should be more like...

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridwidth = 1;
c.ipady = 0;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 4;
c.gridheight = 1;
subpanel.add(bcancel, c);
```

I'd also get rid of the `c.ipady = 26;`, but that's me ;)

And second, make use of the `BOTH` fill constraint...

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.gridwidth = 1;
c.gridx = 3;
c.gridheight = 2;
c.ipady = 26;
subpanel.add(bplus, c);
```

[image: Calculator]

Also...

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (10 == e.getKeyCode()) {
        Rechner rechner = new Rechner(input.getText());
        input.setText(rechner.rechnen().toPlainString());
    }
    if (27 == e.getKeyCode()) {
        input.setText("");
    }
}
```

The `keyCode` doesn't represent ASCII characters, but instead, represents virtual key codes.  You should be using `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` (I think) and `KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE`.  Beware, that a `JTextField` already has capacity to handle the <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the `ActionListener` interface.  In any case, you should consider using the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API if possible

Comment: thx a lot! My TF wouldn't accept the enter code :( if I don't implement it like this... But I will try your solution with KeyEvent...  Where is the  advantage of your solution with KeyEvent

Comment: It will, you need to add an [`ActionListener` to the field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) (and [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html). The advantages of using the `KeyEvent.VK_*` approach is how it's suppose to be used.  The actual hardware key stroke is translated by Java to the virtual key representation

Comment: I'm also get rid of the c.ipady expression it is very unpractical.. exist there a easy way to do it without?

Comment: That depends, what are you trying to achieve

Comment: the same looking ;P But thats not the topic of this question. so I will stuy it later...